# face recognition using surf features and knn search tree

Tags: matlab, face-recognition, surf, knn, matlab-cvst

i have been working on a project on face recognition using surf features and knn search tree using matlab 2014A the problem i am facing is that i am not able to match the results from knn search tree to manually with each file in data base so i can specify which face resembles the sample the most. Can anybody help me how to find the three nearest neighbours in data base?
this is my code

% Combine all features into dataset
    i have 128 surf features for each face in database
    featureDataset = double(vertcat(imageCollection.featureVectors));

```
% instantiate a kd tree
imageFeatureKDTree = KDTreeSearcher(featureDataset);

query.wholeImage = imread('F\:trio.jpg');

faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();
bbox            = step(faceDetector, query.wholeImage)
Out=query.wholeImage;
for k = 1:size(bbox,1)

figure; axesHandle=axes; imshow(query.wholeImage); title('Query Image');
rectangleHandle=imrect(axesHandle,bbox(k,:)) ;

% Consider only selected region
query.image=imcrop(query.wholeImage,getPosition(rectangleHandle));
query.image=rgb2gray(query.image);
% Detect SURF features
query.points = detectSURFFeatures(query.image);
% Extract SURF descriptors
[query.featureVectors,query.points] = ...
    extractFeatures(query.image,query.points,'SURFSize',128);


[matches, distance] = knnsearch(imageFeatureKDTree,query.featureVectors,'Distance','euclidean','K',3);
indexIntervals = [0, cumsum([imageCollection.featureCount])] + 1;
counts = histc(matches(:, 1), indexIntervals);
counts1=histc(matches(:, 2), indexIntervals);
counts2=histc(matches(:, 3+), indexIntervals);
if max(counts)==0
    disp('No Features Matched')
else
    for i = 1:numel(imageCollection) % Scale each image

if (counts(i)==max(counts))        
name=srcFiles(i).name;

end
if (counts(i)==max(counts1))        
name1=srcFiles(i).name;

end
if (counts(i)==max(counts2))        
name2=srcFiles(i).name;
end
    end
    t1 = strcmpi(name(1:10),name1(1:10));t2=strcmpi(name(1:10),name2(1:10));
t3=strcmpi(name1(1:10),name2(1:10));
if((t1==1)||(t2==1)||(t3==1))
Out = insertObjectAnnotation(Out,'rectangle',bbox(k,:),name(1:length(name)-1));
else if (t3==1)

Out = insertObjectAnnotation(Out,'rectangle',bbox(k,:),name1(1:length(name)-1));
    else
Out = insertObjectAnnotation(Out,'rectangle',bbox(k,:),'not matched');
    end
end
end
end
imshow(Out)
```